# SwiftUI drag from one list to another list

Tags: ios, iphone, list, swiftui

I am trying to drag and drop between to Lists.

What I have tried:

I have found a solution  doing it in UIKIt and the using UIViewControllerRepresentable. But that is not what i want.

The other solution was using .onDrag {} on list, but that worked on iPad and didn't work on iPhone.

How to move items between two Lists on iPhone?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. this is not a "we write code for u for free"-platform, but a "we help you with you code"

Comment: This may help you out: https://swiftui-lab.com/drag-drop-with-swiftui/

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

BUT -> as you wrote, it works NOT with list (just on iPad), with VStack
you can drag from left to right or right to left.

```
import SwiftUI


struct BookmarksList2: View {
    @State private var links: [URL] = [
        URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(links, id: \.self) { url in
                Text(url.absoluteString)
                    .onDrag {
                        NSItemProvider(object: url as NSURL)
                }
            }
            .onInsert(of: ["public.url"], perform: drop)
            .onDrop(
                of: ["public.url"],
                delegate: BookmarksDropDelegate(bookmarks: $links)
            )
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Bookmarks")
    }
    private func drop(at index: Int, _ items: [NSItemProvider]) {
           for item in items {
               _ = item.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { url, _ in
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       url.map { self.links.insert($0, at: index) }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
}

struct BookmarksList3: View {
    @State private var links: [URL] = [
        URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(links, id: \.self) { url in
                Text(url.absoluteString)
                    .onDrag {
                        NSItemProvider(object: url as NSURL)
                }
            }
            .onInsert(of: ["public.url"], perform: drop)
            .onDrop(
                of: ["public.url"],
                delegate: BookmarksDropDelegate(bookmarks: $links)
            )
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Bookmarks")
    }

    private func drop(at index: Int, _ items: [NSItemProvider]) {
        for item in items {
            _ = item.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { url, _ in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    url.map { self.links.insert($0, at: index) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BookmarksDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    @Binding var bookmarks: [URL]

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        guard info.hasItemsConforming(to: ["public.url"]) else {
            return false
        }

        let items = info.itemProviders(for: ["public.url"])
        for item in items {
            _ = item.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { url, _ in
                if let url = url {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.bookmarks.insert(url, at: 0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            BookmarksList2()
            Divider()
            BookmarksList3()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: With Xcode 12 beta 2, drag & drop within the same list is working (using .onInsert), but drag & drop between two lists is not working, if the item is dragged onto existing elements, drawn to the end and dropped there, after another item was added first. In this case, there is a crash before the custom drop function is called. It seems to me that the SwiftUI-internal list content management has a bug.