# SwiftUI - Drag Item From One List to Another

Tags: swiftui

There are a few posts on SO asking the same thing as me, but I haven't really found a good answer to this question (some solutions [only work for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61999627), others say it is [not possible in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58629849)). Hoping that someone has more information since I can't find recent discussion on this topic.

In SwiftUI, it is easy to enable "edit" mode on a single list to reorder its items. I am wondering if there is a way to reorder items between two (or more) lists. Not looking for fully fledged out code, but maybe some direction and pointers since I am new to Swift.

Desired Behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyU25.jpg

Comment: It's a good question, but there's no news, so I don't know that it's a good SO question. I don't think there's any way to automate this getting answered. Keep checking the beta notes!

Comment: @Jessy I was hoping someone has figured out a clever solution.  I get that it isn’t supported by default, but thought there might be a workaround